# React/Javascript - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, fetch

React & Javascript noob here, I'm trying to build my first React project. What I want to do is to have a button that fetches automatically the last matches I played on a game. I'm using a API that, when called correctly, returns this json:

```
{data: 
       [{id: 0, internal_id: "_map_id_halo1_pillar_of_autumn", name: "The Pillar Of Autumn"},
…]}
```

I want to extract the name for each object of data and display an unordered list below the button.

But when I click the button, the browser displays the error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')**

The code that does what I mentioned is as follows:

```
async fetchHaloMaps()
    {
        const url = 'https://cryptum.halodotapi.com/games/hmcc/metadata/maps'
        const mapNames = [];

        fetch(url, {
            "method": 'GET',
            "headers": {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Cryptum-API-Version': '2.3-alpha',
                        'Authorization': 'Cryptum-Token XXX'
                     }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.ok)
                throw new Error("Response not ok!");
        })
        .then(response => 
            response.json())
        .then(data => {
                    
            const i=0;
             for (const d of data)
            {
                mapNames[i] = d.name;
                i++;
            }

            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                numberOfMaps : i
            }));
        })  
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("There was an error: " + error);
        });
    }
```

I think I'm "parsing" the JSON in the wrong way. But in the JSON, data i indeed an array with a "name" attribute. So I wanted to cycle the data array and copy the attribute "name", but the code above is not working.
I know the HTTP request with fetch does succeed, since in the console.log I can see the response object and it has the 200 OK field, and I can see the JSON associated with the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not return anything from this `.then`:

```
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response.ok)
            throw new Error("Response not ok!");
    })
```

so there is no value that gets passed along to the next `.then`.

While you *could* do `return response`, a better approach would be to remove the intermediate `.then` entirely - only insert a `.then` when you need to wait for something asynchronous. At the time you get the response, you can check if it's OK *and* then return the `.json()`, without waiting in between.

```
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Response not ok!");
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
```